# question about a theorem regarding monotonous sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, induction

I came across a "theorem" regarding monotonous sequences which states:
let $(a_n)$ be an increasing sequence.

If $m\ge n$ then $a_m\ge a_n$. prove it using induction.

(if you could, please share a proof, since my book doesn't provide one)

I thought that it could be proved in the following way:

$(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence, so for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $a_{n+1}\ge a_n$.

we will use induction in order to prove this theorem (I am not sure whether I need to prove it too for $n$ and a fixed $m$ or just for $m$ and a fixed $n$) :

base case: $m=1$

if $m=1$, then $n=1$. So we get $a_m=a_1\ge a_n=a_1$. Hence, the base case is correct.

inductive step: assume that it is the case that $a_m\ge a_n$, and prove for $m+1$:

since $(a_n)$ is increasing, it is true that $a_{m+1}\ge a_m$. We know that $a_m\ge a_n$ from our hypothesis, and we get:

$a_{m+1}\ge a_n$ for $m\ge n$.

I am assuming this proof is incorrect since I haven't proved it for $n$ and a fixed $m$ too...

Thank you for reading through!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do any induction on $n$. By the definition of what it means to have an increasing sequence, you can directly start with $a_{n+1}\ge a_n$.

Then you say, okay, this the base case $m=1$.